# Why spark streaming is running on previous topics records?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I ran the zookeeper and kafka broker but I didn't run kafka producer.
I ran spark streaming code and print the nonfiltered stream here.
My question is, why I'm receiving these stream of data, namely

> {"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
>
> {"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}

Although I'm not running the producer?
What do these messages mean bellow?

```
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO JobScheduler: Finished job streaming job 1561378800000 ms.0 from job set of time 1561378800000 ms
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO JobScheduler: Total delay: 0.028 s for time 1561378800000 ms (execution: 0.021 s)
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO MapPartitionsRDD: Removing RDD 161 from persistence list
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1716
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1893
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1944
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
{"vehicleId":"0","lon":"0","lat":"0","ts":"0"}
...

19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO KafkaRDD: Removing RDD 160 from persistence list
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1628
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1781
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1570
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO BlockManager: Removing RDD 161
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1808
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 2020
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1624
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned accumulator 1918
19/06/24 20:20:00 INFO ContextCleaner: Cleaned
```

Comment: Each spark stream runs as a new kafka consumer group by default. Kafka consumer groups can be configured to start from the latest offset or the earliest offset. If you find that a consumer is beginning to consume from the very beginning of a topic, check the offset it is reading from. That would be a good place to start debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check what you've set in 'auto.offset.reset'.

From the Spark Streaming Guide:

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)
```

They set the offset reset to "latest". Yours seems to be set to earliest.

Comment: Yes exactly. thank you.
Actually I set "auto.offset.reset" to "smallest" which caused this issue. However, there is difference between Kafka 0.8 and 0.10 related to this value which is "largest" for 0.8 and "latest" in 0.10.